# fetching data from indexed database in HTML 5 and binding to gridview

Tags: json, html, datagridview, indexeddb

I am fetching data from the indexed database in HTML 5, I am able to successfully get the values but I want it to bind it to some data-grid view of ASP.NET
The code which I am using to get the values from the indexed database is

```
if(currentDatabase) {


            var objectStore = currentDatabase.transaction([objStore]).objectStore(objStore);
            var   traveller = [];

            objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
              var cursor = event.target.result;
              if(cursor) {
                    var v = cursor.value;                     
                    traveller.push("id ="+v.id);
                    traveller.push("Name ="+v.traveler);
                    traveller.push("Destination ="+v.destination);
                    traveller.push("Transportation ="+v.transportation);
                    cursor.continue();
                }
```

this allows me to store the data in the array, how can I bind it to datagrid view,

Comment: I'm not familiar with ASP.NET but I'm an expert in IndexedDB. Are you trying to bind from the "Datagrid" view to the database? Namely, whenever someone edits something on the front-end you save that change back to IndexedDB?

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that you put all objects into the same array without hierarchy, and this will result in array that is long `number of properties` multiplied by `number of records` 
Instead what you should do is create an array for each object and then push that array into the main array.

```
var   traveller = [];

objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
    var cursor = event.target.result;
    if(cursor) {
        var v = cursor.value;
        var obj = {};
        obj.push("id ="+v.id);
        obj.push("Name ="+v.traveler);
        obj.push("Destination ="+v.destination);
        obj.push("Transportation ="+v.transportation);
        traveller.push(obj);
        cursor.continue();
    }
}
```